# Trending in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am new to SPFX framework and MSGraph API.

My requirement is to display items trending around me and hence used the API (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/trending). In the response, PreviewImageURL is displayed (which is onedrive API).

I am trying to bind the url to img tag but getting broken image. How to display PreviewImageURL?

Answer (score 0):

Being a beta endpoint, it can be tricky but based on what I'm seeing in Graph Explorer ([see here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/insights/trending/&method=GET&version=beta)), the `previewImageUrl` is a call into the SharePoint REST API.

The prototype for these URLs looks like `https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/thumbnails/0/small/thumbnailContent`. In other words, this URL represents a call into the [SharePoint API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx) rather than a URL to the image itself.

As best I can tell, there is no way to get at this through Graph at the moment. You should however be able to make a second REST call to the `previewImageUrl` to grab the object. Keep in mind this will require that you request additional scopes during authorization to cover the SharePoint API as well.